# How to improve the query in laravel - Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I would like to improve the execution time of the following code. I use it to print student notes.

[image]

To print this, I use the next code:

```html
<tr>
  <td>ESTUDIANTE/TEMA</td>
  @foreach($subjects as $subject)
  <td>{{$subject->name}}</td>
  @endforeach
<tr>
<tr>
  @foreach($users as $user)
    <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
    @foreach($subjects as $subject)
    <?php $subject_view = DB::table('subject_id',$subject->id)->where('user_id',$user->id)->first() ?>
    <td>{{$subject_view->progress}}</td>
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
<tr>
```

The tables are related as follows:

```html
----------------
users
id:integer
name:string
----------------
subjects
id:integer
name:string
----------------
subject_view
id:integer
user_id:integer
subject_id:integer
progress:float
----------------
```

The subject_view table has about 200k rows, how could I improve the query to make it faster?

Comment: Can you please post your controller for this view?

Comment: Can you also post your model relationships between user and subjects please?

Comment: My Controller only return view with $users = DB::table('users')->take(200)->get() and $subjects = DB::table('subjects')->get(). And the model doesn't have relations.

Comment: @user3359775 do you have models? If yes, use eager loading (with Eloquent). Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 1):

1. Avoid fetching the records in the view page. fetch all the results in the controller and parse them to the frontend. create the properly formatted array of subjects in the backend itself before sending.
   its the multiple database calls that's causing your site to slow down.
   You can create a relation between the subjects and they're individual progress and run the laravel eloquent fetch query to get the assocoaitions data as well.
2. In the frontend then you can use something like data tables to sort out ur too many records issue

Answer (score 0):

Avoid doing SQL queries inside a loop. Collect `subject_view`s for all `user_id-subject_id` combinations beforehand and use them in the template.